# Are ready made crossover circuits universally compatible?

Tags: filter, speakers, high-pass-filter

I am planning on modifiying the crossover circuit in a speaker unit. and after doing some research came across a plethora of ready made crossovers available for purchase on the internet (like the one below). My initial thoughts were that a crossover circuit is designed specifically based on speaker driver specifications. Are the ready made one's universally compatible? if so how?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In HiFi loudspeakers the crossover is designed to work with the specific drivers and cabinet for best performance. So, unless the crossover you buy off the internet is specified to work with your particular combination of components or as part of a kit, Its performance will be suboptimal.It will work provided the setup isn't too unbalanced, but it won't be as good as one designed specially for it.
So the question is, why are you modifying the existing crossover which has been optimised for the speaker?

Comment: Existing unit is an el-cheapo :-) only crossover component i see is a filter cap for the tweeter

Comment: it has a dual woofer design, see image here. https://www.diyaudio.com/community/attachments/1678673927168-png.1152991/

Comment: Mention impedance widely differing between transducers even far off resonance(s)?

Comment: @greybeard Agreed. There have been whole textbooks written on loudspeaker design, including crossover networks. Far too much to put in an answer here. For example, changing the volume of the cabinet, adding a port or having a transmission line or horn design will seriously change the characteristics of a driver unit, and hence the crossover it requires.

Comment: @Ahsan I had a quick look at the site you quote for your image in your comment and found this almost imediately https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/introduction-to-designing-crossovers-without-measurement.189847/ It may give you some pointers, but also explain how complicated crossover design can be.